# cut characters from a string in C

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I have a circuit that accepts data (an array of characters to be specific) via bluetooth from my android program.

now, what I want to do is: reprogram my microcontroller, I wish to filter or extract a series of characters from the array that my micrcontroller receives.

My android passes these three kinds of char arrays:

```
1. red#ILOVEYOU
2. blue#ILOVEYOULALALA
3. green#ILOVEDIANAROSECUSTODIO:)
```

I want to extract the red# or blue# or green# and transfer it to other variable. my phone sends a '#' in the end of each colors because I guess it will make the extraction easier.

```
char Comp(char* This){

    while(Serial.available() > 0) // Don't read unless
    // there you know there is data
    {
        if(index < 99){
            inChar = Serial.read(); // Read a character
            if(inChar == '#'){

            }
            inData[index] = inChar; // Store it
            index++; // Increment where to write next
            inData[index] = '\0'; // Null terminate the string

        }
    }

    if(strcmp(inData,This)  == 0){
        for(int i=0;i<19;i++){
            inData[i]=0;
        }
        index=0;
        return(0);

    }
    else{
        return(1);
    }
}
```

This is my code in arduino. You see, it receives one character at a certain very little time and then adds it to a char array variable.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, and most of your variables are undeclared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strtok() function in c.

Comment: that was fast! :) Thanks!~ I'll post my code here later in 30 mins. thanks thanks thanks!~